# C++ legacy application trying to find which part is accumulating memory

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

i have large legacy app that is written in c++ , some part in the application is
accumulating memory in same part or parts in the app . when i triger event in the app 
i can't step in debug this part . there are many a sync in process calls and its 
very hard to follow the flow of the app.
i need to find where are the containers that keeping the data and not getting free 
every time i trigger this event .
what are the recommended tools or methods to help me find the leak ?
i tried to use:
  visual leak detector and c++ Memory validator but it is very hard to find where the problem is.

Comment: If dealing with defects in large code base was easy then lot of us would be without work. A book: "Working Effectively with Legacy Code".

Comment: yes you are right but i need some kind of method in this case

Comment: yes but we do not know the code base nor what problems you encountered with tools that you tried to use, so how we can help?

Comment: a bit late, but did you try valgrind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To paraphrase, `all well-engineered programs are alike; each ancient thrice-ported piece of legacy code is awful in its own way`.

Your major tools in the tool chest, which are broadly independent of your development environment are:

1. Simplify: strip out or replace with NOPs or mock up with trivial implementations as many parts of the code as you can, while retaining the bad behaviour. This will help to remove confounding details.
2. Instrument: check your heap state before and after every call; write debugging info from the constructors and destructors of objects, spitting out their locations, to see where the leaked resources are being allocated; etc.
3. Contracts: implement pre- and post-condition checks on methods, that check for correct resource usage state.
4. Binary search: use a function which checks an invariant that reflects correct resource usage, and use binary subdivision within the problematic section of code to find where it is being violated.

What works in your case is of course hugely dependent upon the details of the code.

Comment: the code base is  to large ( 20 years gods know how many hours they put into i need some tool or method

Comment: Using these sorts of techniques and a debugging malloc library, I was able to track down a heap corruption in a simulator that has been developed over 30 years. It looks overwhelming, and I can't say it won't be work, but these techniques can and do work.